# Using bitfields for parsing network packets

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have the thankless job of writing an IPv6 header parser.

I'm wondering if the version, traffic class and flow control labels could be parsed out using bitfields.

I wrote some test code.  Executing on an x86 system I get unexpected results.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
        uint32_t                flow_label:20;
        uint32_t                traffic_class:8;
        uint32_t                ip_version:4;
} test_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        uint8_t data[] = { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        test_t  *ipv6 = (void *)data;

        printf("Size is %zu, version %u, traffic class %u, flow label %u\n", sizeof(test_t), ipv6->ip_version, ipv6->traffic_class, ipv6->flow_label);
}
```

I'd expect the first nibble to be available in ip_version, but it doesn't seem to be, instead I get:

```
Size is 4, version 0, traffic class 0, flow label 96
```

or with the field order inverted

```
Size is 4, version 0, traffic class 6, flow label 0
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: From a debug point-of-view, use `uint8_t data[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };` and `"version %X, traffic class %X, flow label %X"`  to gain insight into the issue.

Comment: BTW the _first_ nibble with little endian bit/byte order **is** in `"flow label 0"` as the first nibble in that order is 0 from 0x60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bitfields, it's implementation dependent how they are laid out.  You're better off declaring a 32 bit field for the start of the packet and using bit shifting to extract the relevant fields.

```
uint8_t ipver = data[0] >> 4;
uint8_t tclass = ((data[0] & 0xf) << 4) | (data[1] >> 4);
uint32_t flowlbl = (((uint32_t)data[1] & 0xf) << 16) | ((uint32_t)data[2] << 8) | data[3];
```

Indeed, even the Linux netinet/ip6.h header doesn't use a bit field for the ipv6 header:

```
struct ip6_hdr
  {
    union
      {
    struct ip6_hdrctl
      {
        uint32_t ip6_un1_flow;   /* 4 bits version, 8 bits TC,
                    20 bits flow-ID */
        uint16_t ip6_un1_plen;   /* payload length */
        uint8_t  ip6_un1_nxt;    /* next header */
        uint8_t  ip6_un1_hlim;   /* hop limit */
      } ip6_un1; 
    uint8_t ip6_un2_vfc;       /* 4 bits version, top 4 bits tclass */
      } ip6_ctlun;
    struct in6_addr ip6_src;      /* source address */
    struct in6_addr ip6_dst;      /* destination address */
  };
```

Comment: I have seen structures used to parse IPv4 packets use two 4 bit, bit fields for header and version.  I believe OpenBSD does this.  I wonder what that works consistently, but more complex bitfields fail

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell It probably has to do with having bitfields that take up part of one byte and part of another.